# When doing e2e testing with Playwright, components aren't fully loaded before tests run

Tags: javascript, svelte, e2e-testing, playwright, svelte-3

I'm writing a Playwright test for a test page. The page is extremely simple, it makes a fetch to the backend to make sure it's responding (called `liveness`) which will return an OK or FAIL.

```js
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    import { fetchLiveness } from "$lib/request";

    let liveness: string;

    onMount(async () => {
        liveness = await fetchLiveness();
    });
</script>

<div>
    <p>Liveness Check: {liveness}</p>
</div>
```

The test mocks an API call, loads the page, and checks the content of the page for the expected value.

```js
import { expect, test } from "@playwright/test";

test("index page has expected liveness result", async ({ page }) => {
    await page.route('**/liveness', async (route) => {
        await route.fulfill({
            status: 200,
            contentType: "application/json",
            body: "OK"
        });
    })
    await page.goto("/");
    expect(await page.textContent('p')).toBe('Liveness Check: OK');
});
```

Before the fetch completes, the value of liveness is `undefined`. When the test runs, this is what I'm getting as the `textContent` of the `p` element. While I can confirm that the `page.route` callback is being called, it seems it does not wait for the result. so the page is never updated from its initial state before the test finishes.

```bash
    Error: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "Liveness Check: OK"
    Received: "Liveness Check: undefined"
```

I haven't been able to find any info on this, is there something that I need to do to tell playwright to wait for the API request to complete? Or is there something I should be doing in the svelte component so Playwright doesn't think the page load is already completed?

Answer (score 0):

Use [waitForResponse](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-response) so that it will wait for the response before verification.

The key point here to understand is , we need to wait first before calling and loading the page to avoid any race condition.

Code:

```
  await Promise.all([
        page.waitForResponse(resp => resp.url().includes('/liveness') && resp.status()===200),
        page.goto("/");
   ])
        
  expect(await page.textContent('p')).toBe('Liveness Check: OK');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for this particular case, [web-first assertion](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions) is the simplest and also correct approach:

```
await expect(page.locator('p')).toHaveText('Liveness Check: OK');
```